# Dijkstra with Priority Queue, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra with a Priority Queue, but i keep getting this segmentation fault.

My implementation looks like this:

```
void dijkstra_pq_routine(Graph &g, int s, vector<int> &prio,vector<int> &pred)
{
   std::cout << "init" << std::endl;
   int n = g.size();
   prio.assign(n,INT_MAX);
   prio[s] = 0;
   pred.assign(n,-1);
   priority_queue<pii,vector<pii>, greater<pii> > q;

   q.push(make_pair(0,s));

   while(!q.empty())
   {
       std::cout << "while" << std::endl;
       int d = q.top().first;
       int u = q.top().second;
       q.pop();
       if(d != prio[u])
       {
           std::cout << "if" << std::endl;
           //continue;
       }
       std::cout << "before for" << std::endl;
       for(int i = 0;i < (int) g[u].size(); i++)
       {
           std::cout << "for" << std::endl;
           int v = g[u][i].first;
           int nprio = prio[u] + g[u][i].second;
           if(prio[v] > nprio)
           {
               prio[v] = nprio;
               pred[v] = u;
               q.push(make_pair(nprio,v));
           }
      }
   }

   //int len = returnPathLength(prio,(int)g.size()-1);
   //return len;
```

}

the Graph I use looks like this:

```
 typedef pair<int, int> pii;
 typedef vector<vector<pii> > Graph;
```

this produces the error:

```
int main()
{
     Graph g(2);
     g[0].push_back(make_pair(1, 3));
     g[0].push_back(make_pair(1, 1));
     dijkstra_pq(g);
}
```

it seems like the Segmentation Fault occurs before the For loop.
I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: What's `dijkstra_pq()`?

Comment: just a function i call before the routine to init prio and pred

Comment: if(d != prio[u]), are you sure u is not out of bound?

Comment: @swang yes i am. if i cout u and prio.size() this comes out :
-prio.size() : 2 u : 0 prio[u] : 0
-prio.size() : 2 u : 1 prio[u] : 1
-prio.size() : 2 u : 1

Comment: Change every vector `operator[]` use to `vec.at()` and run again. You'll find out in short order where the kitten is getting run-over.

Comment: @Schweigerama: is that all the sequence before it crashes?

Comment: @WhozCraig i done it, but i dont understand why i should see more... can you give me another hint?

Comment: @swang yes, i just use a little graph with 2 vertexes and 2 Edges.

Comment: @Schweigerama if your undefined behavior were due to overreaching vector boundaries, either for read or write, that will expose it without relying on a crash to do so.

Comment: @WhozCraig if i run it with vec.at() i get the same errors, what does that mean then?

Comment: @Schweigerama same *errors* (plural) ? The defect describes *one* error; a segmentation fault at runtime. If the same segmentation fault happens with `.at()` replacing **all** unchecked vector `operator[]` invokes, *and* you built in debug-bits, then your crash isn't related to a vector overrun and its something else (algorithm perhaps).

Comment: I wish I had your `dijkstra_pq` that eventually invokes the function above. Then I could just run it myself and see what gives.

Comment: @WhozCraig its just that:
void dijkstra_pq(Graph &g)
{
    vector<int> prio;
    vector<int> pred;

    dijkstra_pq_routine(g,0,prio,pred);
} and it was singular, sorry

Comment: @enedil yes i tried, but failed to create a executable that gdb takes, because make dumps the exe after the segment fault pops up!

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://ideone.com/kev039). Every line of code in that CNR is fro this question (I did add the "finished" output at the end of the suspect function just to exhibit no early exit), so i don't know what to tell you.